# VSCode macro to switch to previous buffer, not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a macro in vscode like so to switch to the previous buffer:

```
"macros": {
  "switchbuffer": [
    "workbench.action.showEditorsInActiveGroup",
    "selectNextSuggestion",
  ]
}
```

and when I invoke it, it opens the active editors in group but does not "go one down" in the list. How do I invoke an action similar to "downarrow" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - it uses the correct command for the quickpick that is opened:

```json
"macros": {
  "switchbuffer": [
     "workbench.action.showEditorsInActiveGroup",
     "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker"  // note this command
  ]
}
```

This automatically switches to the second entry in the editorsInActiveGroup quickpick.  It works with the macro extension that I am using, [multi command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) which I think is better at running the commands sequentially than the `macros` extension.  If those commands don't work in `maros`, consider switching to `multi command`.

Or see [How can I run multiple commands with a single VS Code keybinding without an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808371/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-with-a-single-vs-code-keybinding-without-an-exte/75808372#75808372) - you don't need a macro extension anymore to run multiple commands.